# RawRabbit serialization issue

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, .net-core, rawrabbit

I'm trying to implement an image processing service using RawRabbit that is going to receive images to be processed and will return the extracted information to a different queue. After removing all the unnecessary code I realized that the problem I am facing is when I call publish from within subscribe delegate.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? My application is based on .Net core 2.0

Below is the method where I subscribe.

```
public async Task StartListening()
    {
        try
        {
            _log.InfoFormat("Preparing to subscribe to queue messages");

            LoadConfiguration();

            CreateBusClient();
            _log.DebugFormat("BusClient created, calling subscribe");

            _client.SubscribeAsync<string>((msgStr, context) =>
            {

                _client.PublishAsync("test", default(Guid), cfg => cfg.WithExchange(exc => exc.WithName("face_process_exchange").WithType(ExchangeType.Direct)).WithRoutingKey("face_process_response"));
                return Task.FromResult(true);

            }, cfg => cfg.WithExchange(exc => exc.WithName(_configuration.Exchange).WithType(ExchangeType.Direct)).
                        WithRoutingKey(_configuration.RoutingKeyToListen).
                        WithQueue(q => q.WithName(_configuration.QueueToListen)).
                        WithSubscriberId(""));

            _log.Info("Subscribed to queue");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            _log.ErrorFormat("Failed to subscribe to queue: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And here is the method where I create the BusClient;

```
private void CreateBusClient()
    {
        var busConfig = new RawRabbitConfiguration
        {
            Username = _configuration.ConnectionUsername,
            Password = _configuration.ConnectionPassword,
            Port = _configuration.ConnectionPort,
            VirtualHost = "/",
            Hostnames = { _configuration.Hostname },
            RouteWithGlobalId = false
        };

        _log.DebugFormat("Calling BusClientFactory.CreateDefault for _configuration read as: {0}", _configuration.ToString());

        var addCfg = new Action<IServiceCollection>(s => s.AddSingleton(p => busConfig));
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddRawRabbit<AdvancedMessageContext>(null, addCfg).BuildServiceProvider();

        var cs = serviceProvider.GetService<IBusClient<AdvancedMessageContext>>();
        _client = new RawRabbit.vNext.Disposable.BusClient<AdvancedMessageContext>(cs);
    }
```

```

The problem is that I always get the following exception when PublishAsync is called.

`` System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Serializing delegates is not supported on this platform.
   at System.MulticastDelegate.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeISerializable(JsonWriter writer, ISerializable value, JsonISerializableContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at RawRabbit.Context.Provider.MessageContextProviderBase1.SerializeContext(TMessageContext messageContext)
   at RawRabbit.Context.Provider.MessageContextProviderBase1.GetMessageContext(Guid& globalMessageId)
   at RawRabbit.Operations.Publisher1.PublishAsync[TMessage](TMessage message, Guid globalMessageId, PublishConfiguration config)
   at RawRabbit.Common.BaseBusClient1.PublishAsync[T](T message, Guid globalMessageId, Action1 configuration)
   at RawRabbit.vNext.Disposable.BusClient1.PublishAsync[T](T message, Guid globalMessageId, Action`1 configuration)
   at SimpleID.FaceProcessing.Services.Implementation.RawRabbitQueueService.b__11_0(String msgStr, AdvancedMessageContext context) ``

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted as a Github issue on the RawRabbit repo and answered by the repo owner (@pardahlman):

https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit/issues/286

> I believe this is an issue with the AdvancedMessageContext. It is
>   possible to fix, but requires registering custom internal services.
>   Before I'll go into the details: do you think it would be at all
>   feasable to migrate to 2.0 (currently in rc1)? This is no longer an
>   issue for that client.