# Internal Server Error when using publishAsync in RabbitMq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, rabbitmq, microservices

I'm trying to build a Message broker using RabbitMq, and an API-gateway that will publish the command to the message broker. But I keep getting a status code of 500 when using the post method.

I've looked at the logs for the RabbitMq server and it seems to authenticate the API and the microservice that is supposed to act on the command sent. I will also attach an image of the logs.

// RabbitMq Logs when running the programs

```
2019-07-17 12:31:24.698 [info] <0.478.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.478.0> ([::1]:64476 -> [::1]:5672)
2019-07-17 12:31:24.773 [info] <0.478.0> connection <0.478.0> ([::1]:64476 -> [::1]:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
2019-07-17 12:31:26.960 [info] <0.485.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.485.0> ([::1]:64479 -> [::1]:5672)
2019-07-17 12:31:27.032 [info] <0.485.0> connection <0.485.0> ([::1]:64479 -> [::1]:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
```

PS. I do not get any kind of logs when there is a POST method. I'm also using postman to send the POST request.

// This is the Controller that receives the commands

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]

    public class ActivitiesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IBusClient _busClient;

        public ActivitiesController(IBusClient busClient)
        {
            _busClient = busClient;
        }

        [HttpPost("")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]CreateActivity command)
        {
            if (command == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(command), "Command can not be null.");

            command.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            command.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
            await _busClient.PublishAsync(command);

            return Accepted($"activities/{command.Id}");
        }
    }
```

// Based on debugging I find that it sends a 500 status code after the

`await _busClient.PublishAsync(command);`

is called. Where it's not sending the command to the Message broker.

// Exception I'm getting when the post command is requested.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware:Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.set_TypeNameAssemblyFormat(System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle)'.
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.RawRabbitDependencyRegisterExtension.<>c.<AddRawRabbit>b__0_1(IDependencyResolver resolver)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.<AddSingleton>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.TryGetService(Type serviceType, Object& service, Object[] additional)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreateInstance>b__4(ParameterInfo parameter)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.CreateInstance(Type implementationType, IEnumerable`1 additional)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.GetService(Type serviceType, Object[] additional)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.<AddTransient>b__2_0[TService,TImplementation](IDependencyResolver resolver)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.TryGetService(Type serviceType, Object& service, Object[] additional)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreateInstance>b__4(ParameterInfo parameter)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.CreateInstance(Type implementationType, IEnumerable`1 additional)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.GetService(Type serviceType, Object[] additional)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.<AddTransient>b__2_0[TService,TImplementation](IDependencyResolver resolver)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.TryGetService(Type serviceType, Object& service, Object[] additional)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreateInstance>b__4(ParameterInfo parameter)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.CreateInstance(Type implementationType, IEnumerable`1 additional)
   at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.GetService(Type serviceType, Object[] additional)
   at RawRabbit.Pipe.PipeBuilder.CreateInstance(MiddlewareInfo middlewareInfo)
   at RawRabbit.Pipe.PipeBuilder.Build()
   at RawRabbit.BusClient.InvokeAsync(Action`1 pipeCfg, Action`1 contextCfg, CancellationToken token)
   at Actio.Api.Controllers.ActivitiesController.Post(CreateActivity command) in C:\Source\Actio\src\Actio.Api\Controllers\ActivitiesController.cs:line 27
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I'm Expecting the code to send an Accepted code where the Activities micro-service should act based on the command sent. For now, I'm just trying to send a create activity command, then the Activity Microservice should receive the command and create the activity. This is my first time working with such a thing and would appreciate any kind of suggestions or feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, All I needed to do is update the version of RawRabbitMq I'm using. I will attach a link to the post that helped me solve the issue.

[RawRabbit serialization issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920433/rawrabbit-serialization-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the version for RawRabbit solved the issue the below issue for me

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.set_TypeNameAssemblyFormat(System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle)'